# Why all objects aren't required during initialization of a class in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I'm working through a TDD book written in Swift to learn how the language is used.  I noticed that in the code base certain objects weren't required to have memory allocated in order to be used.  For example, we created an implicitly unwrapped optional named sut in which I understand allocates memory for this object but doesn't actually create it.  However within the method named setup, we created and used a UIStoryboard object.  I'm confused as to why this is possible and why it's not required to allocate memory for the UIStoryboard object.  Here is the code:

```
import XCTest
@testable import ToDo

class ItemListViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: ItemListViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController

        _ = sut.view
    }

    override func tearDown() {

        super.tearDown()
    }

    func test_TableViewIsNotNil_AfterViewDidLoad() {

        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.tableView)
    }

    func test_loadingView_LoadsTableViewAndSetsTableViewDataSource(){

        XCTAssertTrue(sut.tableView.dataSource is ItemListDataProvider)

    }
}
```

Comment: You're assigning `sut` the result of `storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController`. You don't need to allocate any memory yourself, because `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` did it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already doing it as you declare `let storyboard`, that mean create storyboard constant instance, you declare `var sut` mean you create variable instance, but outside the scope of the function will allow you to use it on other function of the same test class,

You dont need the storyboard instance on other place so you put it in setup as it run everytime you run a test to create new `sut`, a new `sut` will make sure it's standalone and nothing has changed its property

Answer (score 3):

This

```
var sut: ItemListViewController!
```

declares a property named `sut` that is a reference to an `ItemListViewController`.  It doesn't allocate any memory.

`sut` is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so just a normal optional it can be `nil` and Swift won't complain that it wasn't initialised during the initialisation phase.

Since the property is going to be initialised very early in the object lifecycle (In the test's `setup` function) and it isn't initialised conditionally, you "know" that it is going to have a value.

Declaring it as an implicitly unwrapped optional means that you don't need to keep unwrapping the variable each time it is used;  You can just use it, but just like any other force unwrap, you will get a crash if it *is* nil.

Now, this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```

initialises an instance of `UIStoryboard` and links it to the main storyboard in your bundle, and this:

```
sut = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemListViewController") as! ItemListViewController
```

actually performs the allocation of an `ItemListViewController` instance by asking the storyboard object to do so, using the scene with the identifier `ItemListViewController`